# How do to use RefreshControl on a view that does not require ScrollView?

Tags: react-native, flexbox

I have a React Native View, that I would like to allow the user to refresh by pulling down, this View contains fixed content that fits on one screen without the need to scroll, and I have used flex to position the elements to utilised the hold screen.

A quick google tells me I need a [RefreshControl](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/refreshcontrol), but it seems this must be used in conjunction with a [ScrollView](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview).

When I try to apply these two controls to my View I  get undesired effects:

- Scrolls bars that I don't need, although these can be disabled via props
- Flex now responds in a different way, the flex items dont expand to the container, which makes sense because its a scrollable container.

Help :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would indeed reuse RefreshControl in ScrollView, instead creating a RefreshControl behavior yourself.

As you mentioned, scroll indicators can be hidden by setting the correct [props](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview#showshorizontalscrollindicator). In addition it is possible to disable scrolling with the [scrollEnabled](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview#scrollenabled) flag.

A ScrollView uses a built-in content container that wraps all the views inside. You can set [flex style props](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview#contentcontainerstyle) for this view as well.

```
<ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{flex: 1}}>
  {/* child views */}
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: setting `scrollEnabled={false}` prevents the refreshControl from showing/working

Comment: @AngelS.Moreno is right, setting `scrollEnabled={false}` won't work